# vim doesn't load syntax for a single file

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting

I was toying around with my `.vimrc` editing it, and then checking in another file whether my changes worked or not.

But now I ended up in a state where opening one file with `vim file1.tex` (this was the one I used for testing) doesn't load syntax highlighting and using `vim file2.tex` loads the syntax highlighting.

My thought was that maybe I accidentally set something specific for `file1.tex` which persists, but the only info I found was `.viminfo` and deleting that did not help.

Comment: Welcome to this site! Have you tried [How do I debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)? Maybe that will allow you to find out the offending configuration.

Comment: It is definitely NOT my .vimrc, because if I make a copy of said file and open it in vim it works as expected, so it is something that happens to just one specific file and not even related to the contents of the file.

Comment: An `:autocmd` that matches the filename from your `.vimrc` could very well be the reason. Try with a minimal `.vimrc` (that only enables filetype detection and syntax highlighting). I would guess that the problem is gone then. If it isn't, you have to dig deeper; I would open the file from within Vim with `:20verbose edit file1.tex` and check the logs.

Comment: Could this `:autocmd` match the filename only on a given specific path? I will try and check the logs.

Comment: Yes, autocmd patterns can match full / partial paths in addition to the more common filenames. Instead of going through the captured logs, you can also just look at the `:autocmd` output itself. The event probably is `BufRead`.

Comment: Also check `:set ft?` on the problem file, to make sure the file type is being set correctly (compare it to other files or a copy of this file on a path that works...)

Comment: It seems this will remain somewhat of a mystery, as the behaviour disappeared without any input from me. I'm thinking maybe a reboot cleared something ...